# How to get the blackberry uuid using javascript and web works

Tags: javascript, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to find the device UUID using javascript with web works for devices with OS 7 and less.

The code I am using:

```
function getIdentityData(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "http://localhost:8472/blackberry/identity/get",
                success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        }
```

as found in their documentation is not working, I never get the alert? https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.identity.phone.html

I have the following in my config file

```
<rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit> 
<feature id="blackberry.identity.phone" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just blackberry.identity.PIN as documented here - https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.identity.html#.PIN